# Why does Firefox not trust this US government SSL certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates, web-browser

Shouldn't this be a trusted certificate considering it's a wildcard SSL certificate?

That is, shouldn't `*.delaware.gov` cover [www.corp.delaware.gov](https://www.corp.delaware.gov)?

[image: Wildcard SSL certificate]

Comment: See also [this blog post](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) by SE employee Nick Craver, which touches on some related issues involving the implementation of SSL certificates for the SE network.

Comment: MSIE does not trust it either

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The wildcard replaces only one part of the hostname, e.g. *.delaware.gov covers www.delaware.gov or corp.delaware.gov but not www.corp.delavware.gov. From RFC2818, section 3.1:

> ...Names may contain the wildcard character `*` which is considered to match any single domain name component or component fragment. E.g., `*.a.com` matches `foo.a.com` but not `bar.foo.a.com`. `f*.com` matches `foo.com` but not `bar.com`.

Comment: Correct, but is there a way to create a "complete" wildcard SSL cert then ?

Comment: @ack__: Related info at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37887/why-arent-infinite-depth-wildcard-certificates-allowed

Comment: There is no complete wildcard SSL. The solution in this case would have been to have a certificate with subject  alternative names for at least `*.delaware.gov` (exists), delaware.gov (exists) and `*.corp.delaware.gov` (missing). Something like `*.*.delaware.gov` is not allowed.

Comment: RFC6125 tries to unify the different handling of certificates among HTTP, LDAP, SMTP etc, but it does not allow `*.*.example.com` or similar. In section 6.4.3 it clearly states that wildcards should only be used within the left-most label (item 1) and that a `*` should only be compared against the left-most label of the reference identifier (item 2). It explicitely forbids `*.example.com` to match `bar.foo.example.com`. Section 7.2 only acknowledges that not all previous specifications explicitly forbid something like `*.*.example.com`, but neither this RFC nor RFC2818 (HTTPS) allow it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - ***`"... it does not allow *.*.example.com or similar."`*** - Is there any rationale for why this restriction was put in place ? And, does that rationale still apply today ? I don't see any downside in allowing this, other than the lost revenue for SSL Certificate issuers.

Comment: I don't know the real motivation, but I guess it is to let an organization better reflect it structure and control. You often have a main organisation (like university) with a website and then sub-organisations (like department) which manage their own infrastructure. In this case it would be bad if a compromise of the *.university certificate would make it possible to overwrite all *.department.university certificates.